# Rails app with Restforce gem: undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce, restforce

I followed the instructions http://geekymartian.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-4-salesforce-oauth-implementation/
When I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

> `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for`
>   `TomtomCusu::Application:Class`

The method is defined in the *application_controller.rg*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

 private

  def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user

end
```

Comment: move the  helper_method :current_user line below protect_from_forgery with: :exception and above private

Comment: Did it work ...?

Comment: I get the same error